# Looping through JSON data to append a div onto elements on the page

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON file containing details of events that I want to show on a calendar

What I'm looking to do is loop through the JSON data for each day and show a marker on that day on the calendar - just appending an element with the event category as a class to the day on the calendar if an event exists

I've tried creating a loop, but it doesn't quite work. The events also seem to disappear when I change months on the calendar. Here is my loop:

```
for (const entry of eventData) {
        for (const [month, days] of Object.entries(entry)) {
            for (const dayObject of days) {
                for (const [day, events] of Object.entries(dayObject)) {
                    let dayElement = document.querySelector(`[data-calendar-day="${day}"]`);
                    let eventWrapper = document.createElement("div");
                    eventWrapper.classList.add("event-wrapper");
                    dayElement.append(eventWrapper);
                    for (const eventObject of events) {
                        for (const [eventId, details] of Object.entries(eventObject)) {
                            for (const event of details) {
                                let singleEvent = document.createElement("div");
                                singleEvent.classList.add("event", event.category);
                                eventWrapper.append(singleEvent);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using [VanillaCalendar](https://vanilla-calendar.pro/docs/learn/getting-started/installation) which renders each day on the front end in the following format:

```
<div class="vanilla-calendar-day">
    <button class="vanilla-calendar-day__btn vanilla-calendar-day__btn_today" type="button" **data-calendar-day="2024-01-19"** style="flex-direction: column;">
          <span>19</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I've uploaded my demo to [CodePen here](https://codepen.io/OnTheWeb/pen/gOZNzYz), I've added the JSON data inline as I can't link off to my local JSON file but should work the same

If anyone can help out as I'm new to this and a bit stuck, that would be appreciated

Comment: '*but it doesn't quite work*' what *does* happen? I wonder if Vanilla calendar re-updates the html when you change the month, so your updates are wiped out. you may have to re-load them when you change months.

Comment: @mykaf I should have simply said it doesn't work, my events don't show on the calendar. I'm unclear if my approach here with the loop is along the right lines, I'm a bit stuck on it as this is my first time working with JSON.

Comment: What steps have you taken to debug it? Are there any errors in your dev console?

Comment: No console errors - @Unmitigated answer below has helped show the events on the calendar now so I have updated CodePen example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Destructure properties from objects instead of iterating over all key-value pairs with `Object.entries`.
2. You need to zero-pad months and days to two digits in the date when looking for the data attribute.

```js
for (const {month, days} of eventData) {
    for (const {day, events} of days) {
        const key = day.split('-').map(p => p.padStart(2, '0')).join('-');
        let dayElement = document.querySelector(`[data-calendar-day="${key}"]`);
        let eventWrapper = document.createElement("div");
        eventWrapper.classList.add("event-wrapper");
        dayElement.append(eventWrapper);
        for (const {title, category} of events) {
            let singleEvent = document.createElement("div");
            singleEvent.classList.add("event", category);
            eventWrapper.append(singleEvent);
        }
    }
}
```